# NodeJS import error

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, resemblejs

I'm trying to use the resemblejs library (http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) to compare two images. However, when I have created a directory and added resemblejs as a dependency, but when I try to run the following:
`nodejs test.js`, I get the following error

`var api = resemble(fileData).onComplete(function(data){
          ^
ReferenceError: resemble is not defined`

I've never used NodeJS before, so it might be something really simple. Any ideas?

Comment: How to install it ?? Via npm ??

Comment: I did do that. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get directly node module instance from it. You can check [this](https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js/issues/7) issue on its repo. [node-resemble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-resemble) is an Node port of [Resemble.js](https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js).

Hope it will be useful for you.